# getting "peer not authenticated" exceptions connecting to S3 from CDH Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssl, amazon-s3, cloudera

I am trying to run a hadoop job on a Hadoop CDH cluster, and getting below error when the Hadoop Job tries to read data from S3 bucket. Looks like it is trying to connect through SSL. Is there any way I can explicitly disable the SSL connection?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:437)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting the below property in `core-site.xml` resolved the issue. This will disable the SSL connection while connecting to Amazon S3.
Ref: For more details, check out [General S3A Client configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) section.

```
 <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

Update: In my case, I was using `rhel-6.6` with `Cloudera Manager (CM) 5.6.0`, when I updated `rhel` to `rhel-6.10`, I started seeing the above error. The reason for this error was, as per [Cloudera Manager and OS Compatibility list](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/rn_consolidated_pcm.html#os56), `rhel-6.10` is not compatible with `Cloudera Manager 5.6.0`. So I had to upgrade `Cloudera Manager to 5.11.0` to get the above issue resolved.